# PHP FPM download speed on a backup system

Tags: php, nginx, download

i'm making a backup system for a company and I need to understand why i can't get better download speeds using PHP.
The files are on the webserver and I need to bring them to the backupserver. The problem is, using WGET to get the files, i can download them to the backupserver at 50mbps(network limit), but using PHP file_put_contents i can only get like 2mbps if only one file, and when i try to download like 50 files at the same time they get 50kbps each...
Since i'm downloading about 50TB of content, and each file is about 800mb-1.2g, this would take months this way.
I'm using NGINX with PHP-FPM and the configs are perfect everywhere. No limits, no timeouts etc
The code i'm using is basically this example but i'm updating the bytes downloaded in mysql.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-notification-callback.php

Could this problem be related to file_put_contents performance? Is there a solution to get better download speeds?

Comment: You'll need to involve your network admins on this.

Comment: I'm the network admin, i'm taking care of everything, thats why i'm asking here, been trying to solve this for weeks :/

Comment: Ohhhh, I would note that in the question then. I think you'll get better responses.

Comment: Did you check top and see if you're maxing out memory or CPU while trying to download?

Comment: First thought: Why is this not done using proper tools for the job to begin with, like rsync for example? What are your requirements & restrictions on this?

Comment: The files are tokenized, so i need headers to download them, @Nick, i've checked and for some reason its using barely 10% of my cpu, should i increase my pm.max_children and change it to static? also, would increse my fastgci buffers help to make multiple connections to the same file do download it faster?